# Infinite function currying?

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to do the following in scala:

```
def addPoints(x1: Int, y1: Int)(x2: Int, y2: Int)(x3: Int, y3: Int) = {
  doSomethingWith(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
  (addPoints _)
}
```

However, I'm struggling to figure out what the return type of this function should be, as it doesn't seem to be possible to define an infinitely recursive function type. What I'd like to be able to do is the following:

```
type RecursiveFunction2[A, B] = (A, B) => RecursiveFunction2[A, B]

var pointAdder: RecursiveFunction2[Int, Int] = (addPoints _)

def onEvent(x: Int, y: Int) {
  pointAdder = pointAdder(x, y)
}
```

However, types are not able to reference themselves. Is there any way to accomplish this without resorting to having a return type of `Any`, and calling `asInstanceOf[Function2[Int, Int, Any]]`?

Comment: Can you comment more on what you want `addPoints` and `doSomethingwith` to do and why the function needs to be 'infinitely-recursive'?

Comment: Sure, essentially I have 0 - ∞ x,y coordinate pairs that are going to come in through an event driven interface. Every third set, I need to do something with side effects. There's plenty of ways to implement it, but it seemed like it would be interesting to do this with currying, since it would work infinitely, as long as I could continue to call the curried function. Having it return itself would allow me to always have a signature of (Int, Int) => Function2.

Comment: What about modeling that behavior as a `fold` over a `Stream`?

Comment: I'm only vaguely familiar with `Stream`, could you demonstrate an example of how that might look?